# Android Studio Emulator black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio 1.3.2 to develop an android app and I am also using its emulator, I am trying to run the app on the emulator by creating AVD: Nexus 6 API 23 and when I run the app I can see only the nexus 6 with black screen, not even the android home screen.
I saw that some people asked about this problem but none of the answers they got helped me to solve it.
Does anyone know how to solve this ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: which configurations are you using for setting up the emulator?

Comment: Sorry but I am new to this. how can I check configurations ? @Aakash
thanks.

Comment: when you are creating the virtual device, which options are you selecting over there , for ex: system image, use host GPU etc ?

Comment: Device: Nexus 6. Release Name: Marshmallow. API Level 23. ABI: x86
I tried to activate and deactivate "USE HOST GPU" and also tried to activate "Store a snapshot for faster startup" but none of them worked.
@Aakash

Comment: can you try using nexus 5?

Comment: I tried and I got the same problem.. @Aakash

Comment: i am using the same configuration and that's working for me, no idea what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Emulator from Genymotion for Personal Use.

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

It's better.

Comment: The android studio emulator is too slow, does the Genymotion faster ? 
Thanks man, I'll try it.